# Plotting a legend for facet grids

Tags: python, seaborn

I have plotted around 10 graphs using facet grids in seaborn. How can I plot a legend in each graph? This is the current code I have:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(masterdata,row="departmentid",col = "coursename",hue="resulttype",size=5, aspect=1)
g=g.map(plt.scatter, "totalscore", "semesterPercentage")
```

If I include `plt.legend()`, then the legend only appears in the last graph. How can I plot a legend in each graph in the facet grids plot? Or is there a way to plot the legend in the first graph itself, rather than the last graph? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a legend to each axis individually if you iterate over them. Using an example from the seaborn docs:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  hue="smoker")
g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", edgecolor="w")

for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.legend()
```

The reason we have to use `.ravel()` is because the axes are stored in a `numpy` array. This gets you:

[image: Facetgrid with individual legends]

So in your case you will need to do

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(masterdata,row="departmentid",col = "coursename",hue="resulttype",size=5, aspect=1)
g.map(plt.scatter, "totalscore", "semesterPercentage")

for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.legend()
```

To only show the legend in the top-left graph, you want to access the first `axes` in the `numpy` array, which will be at index `[0, 0]`. You can do this by doing e.g.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  hue="smoker")
g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", edgecolor="w")

g.axes[0, 0].legend()
```

Which will get you:
[image: Facetgrid with legend in first axes]