# A facet-specific legend in each facet of a FacetGrid Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to make a facet-specific legend in each facet of a `FacetGrid Seaborn` object, such as that produced by a `catplot`. 
Consider the following `DataFrame` where `measurement` is the variable to plot, against the categorical `Condition`, faceted across rows and columns according to variables `Lab` and (instrument) `model`. The `hue` is set to the serial number of the particular instrument on which the measurement was made.
Here is the `DataFrame`:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'Condition': ['C1','C2','C1','C2','C1','C1','C2','C1',
                                 'C1','C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2'],
                   'model': ['Pluto','Pluto','Jupy','Jupy','Jupy','Jupy','Jupy','Jupy',
                             'Jupy', 'Pluto', 'Pluto', 'Pluto', 'Pluto', 'Pluto', 'Jupy', 'Jupy',
                             'Pluto'],
                   'serial': [2520,2520,3568,3568,3568,3580,3580,356,
                              456, 2580, 2580, 2580, 2599, 2599, 2700, 2700, 
                              2560],
                   'measurement': [1.02766,1.0287,1.0099,1.0198,1.0034,1.0036,1.0054,1.0024,
                            1.0035,1.00245,1.00456, 1.01, 1.0023, 1.0024, 1.00238, 1.0115, 
                            1.020],
                   'Lab': ['John','John','John','John','Jack','Jack','Jack','John',
                           'Jack','John', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'John', 'John', 
                           'John']}
                  )
```

some facets contain only a subset of the `hue` levels and as the levels grow in number the `FacetGrid` legend gets rather long. Inspired by an the answer to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206343/plotting-a-legend-for-facet-grids), I opt for iterating through the `FacetGrid` `axes` using `g.axes.ravel()` to get a legend in each facet:

```python
sns.set_style("ticks")
g = sns.catplot(x='Condition', # returns a FacetGrid object for further editing
            y = 'measurement', 
            data=df, 
            hue='serial',
            row='Lab', 
            col='model',
            s=10,
            kind='swarm',
            dodge=False, 
            aspect = 1,
            sharey = True,
            legend_out = True,
            ).despine(left=True)

for axes in g.axes.ravel():
    axes.legend()
g.savefig('/Users/massimopinto/Desktop/legend_in_facets.png', 
          bbox_inches='tight')
```

this leads to a rather crowded plot and overloaded information from the entire `FacetGrid` object legend. What I would prefer to have is the legend of each facet *only* to show the `hue` levels that appear in that specific facet. 
How do I get to that?

[image: towards a facet-specific legend]

versions: pandas: 1.0.3; seaborn: 0.10.0; python: 3.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider iterating elementwise with a `groupby()` object using `zip` to rebuild each legend by corresponding values of *hue* column. Importantly, you must sort data frame before plotting.

```
df = df.sort_values(['Lab', 'model', 'serial']).reset_index(drop=True)

sns.set_style("ticks")
g = sns.catplot(x = 'Condition',                  
                y = 'measurement', 
                data = df, 
                hue = 'serial',
                row = 'Lab', 
                col = 'model',
                s=10,
                kind='swarm',
                dodge=False, 
                aspect = 1,
                sharey = True,
                legend_out = False,               # REMOVE MASTER LEGEND
               ).despine(left=True)

# MASTER SERIES OF serial
ser_vals = pd.Series(df['serial'].sort_values().unique())

for axes, (i, d) in zip(g.axes.ravel(), df.groupby(['Lab', 'model'])):
    handles, labels = axes.get_legend_handles_labels()

    # SUBSET MASTER SERIES OF serial
    vals = ser_vals[ser_vals.isin(d['serial'].unique())]    
    idx = vals.index.tolist()

    if len(idx) > 0:
       axes.legend(handles = [handles[i] for i in idx], 
                   labels = vals.tolist())
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: Thank you. I might better put it into a function for reuse. May this hopefully be considered as a future legend feature in `seaborn`.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a useful feature. Since `seaborn` is open source, maybe contribute to the project or [suggest it as a request](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+facetgrid)!

Comment: It would be great to contribute to the project as I get to learn more how to use it. Meanwhile, I have followed your suggestion and made a [fresh request](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2043).

Comment: Your answer, @Parfait, sorts it out, but a general procedure should account for the possibility that the number of `axes` and the size of the `groupby` object are _not_ the same. When one or more facets are empty (I have one such case in another dataframe), that is when there are no data to be plotted in a specific facet, one ends with a  `list index out of range` error in the line `hdls = [handles[i] for i in idx]` that is par of your answer. One solution may be to delete the critical `axes`,  it's too manual to be a general approach.

Comment: Although the answer by @Parfait works well for the dataframe given as example here, there are cases in which the code fails, and that is when one or more of the facets is empty. A more general solution was provided by the very author of the `seaborn` package in the thread associated to my request, [https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2043#issuecomment-621911624](here). The use of `seaborn` that I am making here, however, is somewhat unorthodox, as seaborn's legends are intended to cover _every_ facet of the graph.

Comment: Understood. Curious, how do you have empty facets in the data? Usually `groupby` is consistent with *hue*. Do you have groups with `NaN`s in numeric column? With your original code, did empty facets show? Also, GitHub solution essentially builds different subplots onto a defined `FacetGrid` (i.e., multiple `sns.swarmplot` calls) and does not adjust axes with `sns.catplot`. With that, you wouldn't even need `FacetGrid` but can run `matplotlib` subplots!

Comment: I have empty facets when a particular choice of faceting leave one facet devoid of data to plot (nothing from the `groupby` object to be plotted in that facet). In that case, the two iterators that you zipped together in your response have different lengths, and this lead to the `list index out of range` that I was alluding to.  In the dataframe that I did not post here, all facets do show but some could be empty. I am probably making a weird use of the logic of `seaborn`.

Comment: See updated using `if` logic to conditionally add adjusted legends to each facet axes.

Comment: yes @Parfait the `if` logic is a good working solution to the iteration breaking over `[handles[i] for i in idx]` . Cheers.